# "%1$s" showing up in formatted resources string alongside correctly formatted variable text

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I have the following string in my strings.xml:

`<string name="end_test_msg">Your score is: %1$s%%</string>`

I'm using this in a DialogFragment builder as the .setMessage function's parameter (score is a String from a float or int):

```
    class EndTestDialogFragment(percent: Double) : DialogFragment() {
        //Converts percent to a string, truncates ".00" if it's a whole number.
        private val score: String = when(percent.compareTo(percent.toInt()) == 0) {
            true -> percent.toInt().toString()
            false -> String.format("%.2f", percent)
        }

        override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
            return activity?.let {
                val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it)
                builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.end_test_title))
                builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.end_test_msg, score))
                    .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok),
                        DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id ->
                            this.activity?.finish()//Return to the MainActivity
                        })
                // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
                builder.setCancelable(false)
                builder.create()
            } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Activity cannot be null")
        }

    }
```

Rather than getting "Your score is: 50%" (or whatever appropriate number) the dialog is showing "Your score is: %1$s%% 50%". It does this regardless of whether score comes from the .toInt()... or the formatted double. What am I doing wrong? It's bizarre to me that I'm seeing both the placeholder and the correctly formatted string.

In case its placement matters, the EndTestDialog class is defined within the Activity that is using it. When I use the exact same formulation within the Activity (but in a TextView, not a Dialog) it displays fine without showing the placeholder.

Please forgive me if I'm overlooking the obvious; I'm very new to Android/Kotlin.

Comment: I'm curious how you converted your **score** variable from a float/int value.

Comment: I just checked to see if the double was a whole number, and called .toInt().toString on it if so, or just .toString if not.

Comment: You don't have to convert the **score** variable into String: just use _%1$d%%_ for a whole number. Or, just  _%d%%_ since you only have one position.

Comment: You can simply use _%1$f%%_ or _%f%%_ if the **score** variable is a float. If you want to format its float value (say, 0.05156) as '0.05%,' use _%1$.2f%%_ or _%.2f%%_.

Comment: Assuming that only one positional string is to be replaced in the resource string, if the float value is 10.05156 but only needs to be formatted as '10%' (a whole number), use _%.0f%%_. Of course, it is preferable to cast the float as an integer and use _%d%%_ instead.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with what you've posted - you might want to post your actual code (including how you calculate `score`) and the logged output (so you can copy exactly what it produces). You're summarising here but I feel like the problem is in the little details somewhere, being able to see exactly what's happening might provide some clues

Comment: OK, I posted the full code for the class. I'll see if I can figure out posting the logged output. Like I said, I'm very new to Android, and haven't really done much programming in years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a copy-paste error. I'm so sorry to waste your time; I was accidentally calling a fully qualified version of a similar dialog from another Activity, and not the one defined in the class in question. The two identical classes are now defined in a single file and it is used by both Activities.

*Dies of embarrassment.*